# Subtracting value of a particular column where a value of particular column is same in both tables

Tags: mysql, sql

My db has two tables `stock` and damage.

`stock` table looks like

```
item_code, ss_no, item_name, rack_no, shelf_no, cold_storage, batch_no, qty, packing, expiry_date, mrp, purchase_price, selling_price, margin, formulation, stock_date, min_qty, ss_flag_id, ban_flag_id, sales_discount
'1', 1, 'ABZORB POWDER', 'A-1', ' ', ' ', '9086626', 18, 1, '2017-06-01', 87.00, 66.29, 87.00, 0.00, 'POWDER', '2015-05-11', 0, 0, 0, 0.0
```

`damage` table looks like the below

```
damage_stock_date, invoice_no, invoice_date, dist_name, contact_no, item_code, item_name, batch_no, mfr_name, expiry_date, qty, damaged_qty, unit_price, unit_vat, unit_discount, sub_total, total_amount, remarks, ds_flag_id, packing
'2015-06-19', '56', '2015-06-19', 'Ganapati Drugs', '', '0', 'SAXIM_', '1', '', '', 50, 10, 2.00, 5.00, 0.00, 21.00, 21.00, '', 0, 0
```

If I want to select a row from stock where the value of `item_name` column in both the tables, I would use

```
select * from stock s where item_name in
( select item_name from damage);
```

which does the job exactly what I want.

Now I want to subtract the value of `qty` col in `damage` from `stock`'s `qty` col where the value of `item_name` from both the columns must be same.

I think I have to use variables but I don't know how..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using join:

```
select *, (s.qty-d.qty) as available
from stock s LEFT JOIN
     damage d on d.item_name=s.item_name
where d.qty IS NOT NULL
```

Example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef77c/1).

**Explanation:**

A left join with table `damage` with condition `d.qty IS NOT NULL` would do the same thing. It is same as using `IN` (as in your question). But the advantage is that, you can use the columns of `damage` table in the main query.

So you can find the available quantity by `(s.qty-d.qty)`

**EDIT:**

For updating the table:

```
UPDATE  stock s LEFT JOIN 
        damage d ON d.item_name = s.item_name
SET     s.qty=(s.qty-d.qty)
WHERE   d.qty IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: seems like working , could you add some more explanation to your post?

Comment: @user197324: I have updated my answer. Feel free to ask for clarification if needed.

Comment: upvoted. I'm trying to update the column with the subtracted value but i's not working `update stock set s.qty = s.qty-d.qty LEFT JOIN
     damage d on d.item_name=s.item_name
where d.qty IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @user197324: Your question was for `select`. Anyway, updated my answer with update query. See the edit.

Comment: I discourage you from updating the quantities in `stock`. If you must update the quantities, you should probably do so within a transaction where you also `DELETE` the `damage` records. A better practice would be to create a `net_stock` view that looks like `stock` but has the damaged quantities deducted.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there can be multiple `damage` entries for each `stock` item.  Therefore, you need to use an aggregating subquery on `damage` before joining.

```
SELECT *, stock.qty - total_damage.qty AS remaining_qty
    FROM stock,
        (SELECT item_name, SUM(qty) AS qty
            FROM damage
            GROUP BY item_name) AS total_damage
    WHERE stock.item_name = total_damage.item_name;
```